# Q: Can we use Bundles for Releases using content porter

Tags: 2013, bundles, content-porter-2013

We are starting to experiment with Tridion 2013, and came across the Bundles.

The thirst thing that pops in mind, can we use bundles for releasing schema's and templates?

For example, i would create a bundle called "Tridion Release 1.0" on the lowest publication possible, so that we can get items from across all publications. Assuming the items we add to the bundle will be webdav based path locations. And then use Content Porter for exporting just the bundle to Test / Acceptance and Production? I'm assuming it would be possible and all related items in the bundle will be part of the export. But if the bundle is like a virtual folder, then i'm no longer so sure that this idea would work.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can use bundles for Content Porter Export... unfortunately, the current version of Content Porter will export the items from the *same* publication that you're exporting the bundle from... so not extremely useful.

As from 2013 SP1 (coming out soon) you'll be able to tell Content Porter to export the items in a bundle from their `Parent` (or `Owning`) publication instead.

**EDIT** 
See also Will's excellent post on [using Bundles for release management](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/simple-release-management-with-sdl-tridion-2013-and-bundles).